# Как научить telegram-бота осуществлять поиск информации на сайте?

Tags: java, поиск, telegram-bot, поисковые-системы

Бот должен при запросе по ключевому слову(напр. "Автомобиль"), возвращать изображение искомого объекта. Каким образом реализовать поиск?

Возможно ли подключиться к поисковым системам? Или все же лучше взять какой либо ресурс и парсить его при помощи JSoup,дело в том что поиск будет по определенной тематике. Но есть второй вопрос, не слишком ли запарно будет парсить ресурс, что бы взять всего лишь одно изображение?

Реализую бот на Java, есть ли возможность подключить к поисковику?

Comment: Я предполагаю, что нужно иметь программу, которая стоит на сервере с ботом и через нее делать поиск. Посмотрите исходники аналогичных ботов, чтобы точно сделать все правильно (например, у Яндекса есть такой бот).

Comment: @RostislavDugin спасибо

Comment: https://telegram.me/pic - ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Каким образом реализовать поиск?

Самое очевидное и общее решение – с помощью поисковых систем. Можно использовать, например, [Google Images](https://images.google.com/), [Яндекс.Картинки](https://yandex.ru/images/), либо какие-то другие, локальное ресурсы.

> Возможно ли подключиться к поисковым системам?

Да, возможно. Однако, в случае высокой частоты запросов, Вам необходимо будет как-то обработать ситуацию с введением капчи. Основные методы решения:

- Использовать сервис по ручному распознаванию текста с изображений вроде antigate.com и ему подобных;
- Использовать прокси (частичное решение);
- Просить пользователя ввести код с картинки;

*Варианты расположены в случайном порядке, а не в порядке приоритета. Конечное решение зависит от конкретной задачи.*

> Или все же лучше взять какой либо ресурс

В поисковых системах можно ограничить область поиска определенными доменами, например, в Google это можно сделать так:

```
site:stackoverflow.com график
```

При поиске изображений по этому запросу Вы получите найденные изображения по ключевому слову «график» в пределах домена `stackoverflow.com` (и его поддоменов).

Тут стоит заметить, что релевантность поисковой выдачи в некоторых случаях может быть низка.

Comment: Ух ты ж, интересная информация, спасибо